# SwiftUI how to update newly selected images to cells

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm making an iOS app and I want to display some sort of default image (or just blank) in a row view, and then update them to new selected images by users. [How the app currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMOGS.png)
How can I update the images in the cells to be the new ones users select?

This is how I am creating the row views and cells

```
import SwiftUI

struct Row: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let cells: [Cell]
}

extension Row {

}

extension Row {

    static func all() -> [Row] {
        var resultRow = [Row]()

        for _ in 1...10 {
            resultRow.append(Row(cells: [Cell(imageURL: "camera"), Cell(imageURL: "camera")]))
        }

        return resultRow  
    }    
}

struct Cell: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let imageURL: String
}
```

And my UIView looks like this

```
import SwiftUI

struct PhotoUIView: View {
    @State private var showImagePicker: Bool = false
    @State private var image: Image? = nil

    let rows = Row.all()

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            List {
                ForEach(rows) { row in
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        ForEach(row.cells) { cell in
                            Image(cell.imageURL)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: -20, bottom: 0, trailing: -20))

            image?.resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            if (image == nil) {
                Text("Upload photo to begin quick design")
            }

            Button("Select photo to upload") {
                self.showImagePicker = true
            }.padding()
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)

            Button("Begin Quick Design") {
                print("Here we upload photo and get result back") 
            }.padding()
                .background(Color.green)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)

        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
            PhotoCaptureView(showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$image)
        }
    }
}

struct PhotoUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PhotoUIView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do is, creaate an array of images and add those selected images with name like image_0, image_1, and so on. And then add the images in the cell using the array eg a[i]